# HTACCESS redirect to index.php: PHP level in subfolder fix

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My current HTACCESS looks like this.

```
# Run everything else but real files through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Great piece of code where when I type in what would be a subfolder directory, it redirects as a parameter to index.php. Works great for something `http://localhost/blah` (which redirects as `http://localhost/index.php?p=blah`), but not so great for `http://localhost/blah/boink`.

The problem with the latter is that the redirection does work and does redirect to index.php, but for some reason, the page believes that it is at the subfolder level, `blah`. So all my hardcoded `../` for my `js`, `css`, `include` and `require_once` paths are now technically "wrong". Anyway of fixing this?

In PHP, when I try to do this:

```
$file_url = explode("/", $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

// subtract 1 for left / and 1 for current file
$dir_loop = count($file_url) - 2;
$up_dirs = "";
// loop until to root directory

for ($i=0; $i<$dir_loop; $i++) {
    $up_dirs .= "../";
}
```

...this doesn't seem to work either, because the index.php is at the root folder level. I suspect this may be a HTACCESS issue? Thoughts?

Comment: Use the `<base>` tag for linking to JS/CSS etc.

Comment: _“but for some reason, the page believes that it is at the subfolder level, `blah`”_ – that’s not a “belief,” but simply the reality. The _client_ is the one that resolves relative paths to absolute ones, and the _client_ has requested the document from the address `http://localhost/blah/boink`. That is all it knows; it is not aware of whatever your _server_ does with the request _internally_.

Comment: you can always exempt specific dirs, e.g. `rewritecond !^(js|css|include)/` And note that require/include in PHP operate at the filesystem levely. unless you're doing something (stupid) like `include('http://yoursite.com/include/foo.php')`, anything php does to load a file will NEVER be seen by apache or mod_rewrite.

Comment: What is the use of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$`?

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ron van der Heijden clued me into: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$`. Modified the code as follows:

```
# Run everything else but real files through index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*\.(js|css|png|jpe?g|gif|ico)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```